# Complete theory with quantifier elimination has finite boolean algebra

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, boolean-algebra, quantifier-elimination

I have the following problem written down:

If $\mathcal{L}$ has a finite signature, with no functions, and $T$ is a complete theory with quantifier elimination, then the boolean algebra of $\mathcal{L}$-sentences $\mod T$ is finite.

This seems straightforward, with no functions the only quantifier free sentences are $\mathsf{R c_0 ... c_k}$, and finite signature means there are only finitely many relations and constants to choose from. Of course $T$ might think some of these sentences are equivalent, but that's fine.

Where have I used completeness? Am I wrong or is it unnecessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct that completeness is unnecessary.  In fact, it is almost certainly an error that completeness was included in the problem statement, since it makes the problem rather trivial: modulo any complete theory, every sentence is either true or false (by completeness!), so the Boolean algebra would have only two elements.

Comment: Oh gosh, I should have caught that triviality. Much appreciated.